# A tidy solution for using static JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm developing a simple JavaScript (jQuery) slide show. I wanted to use JSON to store some some static parameters about the content of each slide.

Since I like to keep my data separate from my code, is there anyway to have JavaScript evaluate a .json file?

- AJAX seems a bit overkill - it just needs to evaluate it at run-time, nothing is dynamic.
- I could have a separate .js file that holds my JSON data as an object - but this seems messy.

So before I use one of the above solutions, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a cleaner way to have JavaScript evaluate a text file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with having a separate js file for your object? It has to live somewhere. I agree ajax is overkill, but I'm at a loss for why you think a JavaScript object in a .js file is "messy."

Comment: Agreed. Having it in a JS file is similar to having it stored anywhere else - think of config files or XML, etc. - Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: In fact it makes your life less messy!

Comment: So you don't want it in your code, retrieved by code, or linked? That pretty well leaves it in a hidden input, which is even tackier. I'm with these guys: an external .js is the cleanest option.

Comment: Ah ok , it's not extremely messy and that's what I was leaning towards - I just wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way to evaluate a file, this way your data is truly kept separate from your code. I mean having a .js file with var JSON = "..."; isn't that big of a deal, but it kind of goes against the whole semantic web ideology, regardless of the fact that no one else will be reusing this data.

Comment: How is the data for the slides stored?

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating JSON is very easy:

```
var jsonString = "{'name': 'Joe', 'age': 36}";

var data = eval('(' + jsonString + ')');
data.name // 'Joe'
data.age  // 36
```

The easiest way to store this data is to put it in an `<input type="hidden">` and then read it using `document.getElementById('hiddenElementId').value`.

---

The complete picture:

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenElementId" value="{'name': 'Joe', 'age': 36}" />
```

**JS**

```
function getData() {
     var jsonString = document.getElementById('hiddenElementId').value;
     var data = var data = eval('(' + jsonString + ')');
     return data;
}
```

It's not actually necessary to be a `hidden` element - you can put it in an attribute in one of the images.

---

Another option is to stick it into a `<script>` tag under some name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {'name': 'Joe', 'age': 36};
</script>
```

This way `data` becomes a global variable (something I don't like so much) and can be used from everywhere. It's a simple solution, but a bit messy - I would go with the first one.

Comment: To evaluate a JSON string you can use `JSON.parse(string)` although I don't know about IE.

Comment: Fr all browsers you can use JSON.parse if you use the JSON library. Most people frown upon the eval. Newer browsers have a "safe" parse.

Answer (score 1):

J-Query has a parse JSON function that even works in IE..

```
$.parseJSON("{'json':'rules for data'}");
```

Enjoy..

but just a question how to make it tidy like:

```
FUNCTION_HOWTO({json:'test',p2:'part2'}) = {
    json:'test',
    p2:'part two'
}
```